# Regular Expression for converting old-style C++ initialization with C++11 initialization, using any open-source tool

Tags: c++, regex, eclipse, c++11, emacs

Is there a robust way of converting C++ initialization syntax to C++11 initialization syntax on an entire project using a find/replace in Eclipse, or a grep with a tr, or vi or emacs? I'm looking to do this on an entire project, and am willing to deal with the inevitable errors if it isn't perfect, but I just can't figure out the right regex.

To give a concrete example, I'd like this to convert

```
bool b(true);
```

to

```
bool b{true};
```

Even if the error rate was 10%, it would be tolerable.

Comment: have you tried `(bool [a-zA-Z]+)\(([^)]*)\)` with `$1{$2}` as replacement?

Comment: clang modernize is the tool you are looking for...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Wow 123450 rep? Need to get you 6 more! :)

Comment: Btw, any particular reason for the change? If it ain't broken...

Comment: This is more an experiment--I'd never deploy but I'd like to see if it could become part of a more readable and modern codebase.